# Run specific set of XCUITests

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

The problem is that I want to be able to run specific amount or group of XCUITests, like in Calabash for example. In Calabash you can run a set of tests marked with specific tag.
So, I was wondering is there anything that I can do to achieve this? 
I know that I can split group of tests by bundle or even scheme, but thats not what I am looking for.

So, far I saw that you can run only specific test, but not a group of tests.

EDIT:

Basically I want to be able run command something like:

xcodebuild test -workspace  -scheme  -destination  -only-testing:UITestBundle -tag

In that way I would be able to test only specific functionality related to small area of my project, so it would not be needed to run all bundle which could potentially take a lot of time. And I would be able to set up this in CI. And it would not be necessary to change my code every time when I need to run different set of tests.

Answer (score 3):

You can govern the execution by Launch arguments and skip the tests based on the corresponding values. Create a Launch Arg like `IsSkippingTests` and set a value based on your requirement, then at the beginning of each test you can add the the code like:

```
guard LA.valueOfLA("-IsSkippingTests") == "requiredFunctionality" else { return }
```

And define a struct `LA` which will contain `valueOfLA` static method:

```
public struct LA {
static public func valueOfLA(key: String) -> String? {
    var arguments = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments

    if let index = arguments.indexOf(key) where index + 1 < arguments.count {
        return arguments[index + 1]
    }

    return nil
}
```

So based on the value which you supply you can execute set of tests and skip the ones which you don't want. You can also set multiple values and modify the valueForLA method to handle it.

Comment: Yes, but then I need to modify my code base every time when I want to run another set of tests. This method as I understand is very good when you need completely disable few tests for a time being, but I need something more dynamic. Something like run configuration or dynamic bundle building, so I can change set quickly and run specific tests on CI.

Answer (score 2):

it is now possible with possible with xcode 8. Check this video

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/409/.

[image]

Comment: So, it is not kinda what I am looking for. Because then every time when you need to change different set of tests, you need to create new test bundle, and this is kind of pain in the ass. Also, I am using CI, so it is really hard to configure dynamically what exact set of tests you want to run.